# How to reshape multi-dimensional matrix to 2-d and vice versa?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this function `f` that takes an `n x dx` matrix and returns an `n x dy` matrix. Now I have an `n1 x dx x n2`, so I need to reshape it to an `n1*n2 x dx` and then reshape the results back again to `n1 x dy x n2`. This is my code:

```
function main
n1 = 4;
n2 = 5;
dx = 2;
dy = 3;
x = ones(n1, dx);
x = bsxfun(@times, permute(1:n2, [1, 3, 2]), x)
x2d = reshape(permute(x, [1 3 2]), n1*n2, dx)
y2d = f(x2d)
y = permute(reshape(y2d', dy, n1, n2), [2 1 3])

%%
% x = cat(4, x, x+3)

end

function y = f(x)
y = [x, sum(x, 2)];
end
```

Well, problem begins where I need higher dimensions of samples. I'm really stuck with 4-dimensional matrices, like `cat(4, x, x+n2)`. So is there a general solution that reshapes these:

```
n1 x dx x n2 x ... x nm -> (n1*n2*...*nm) x dx
(n1*n2*...*nm) x dy     -> n1 x dy x n2 x ... x nm
```

Comment: Can't you redefine `f` so it can take an n-dimensional array?

Comment: @rahnema1, well, there are tens of them! Those are actually predefined cost functions. So I really prefer not to mess with them.

Comment: Nevertheless I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to `permute` the second dimension and then do a `reshape`, and vice versa:

```
% assume size(arr) is [n1, dx, n2, n3, ..., nm]
permuted = permute(arr, [1, 3:ndims(arr), 2]);  % [n1, n2, n3, ..., nm, dx]
final = reshape(permuted, [], size(permuted, ndims(permuted)));
```

And for the reverse transform:

```
% assume size(arr) is [n1*n2*n3*...*nm, dy]
% and you have to know new_size = [n1, n2, n3, ..., nm]
% and watch out for dy == 1 case: trailing singleton is removed
reshaped = reshape(arr, [new_size, size(arr, numel(new_size)+1)]);  % [n1, n2, n3, ..., nm, dy]
final = permute(reshaped, [1, numel(new_size)+1, 2:numel(new_size)]);
```

You might have to watch out with edge cases with few dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing multiple reshapes and permutes you can redefine `f` so it can take a n-dimensional array.

```
function y = f(x)
    y = cat(2,x,sum(x,2));
end
```

Comment: As I said before, redefining `f` is not an option in my case. But you have a point there for people who may come by. So 1+.